# Difference and meaning between "remastered" and "remake"

Tags: terminology

Since there are currently rumors that Bethesda is make a "remastered" Version of one of their games(most say Skyrim), I was wondering what exactly is "remastered"? And what's the difference to a "remake"? Same thing?

Or are there certain criteria for either one of them?

What kind of stuff would be expected in such versions? Most of the time the title now contains an HD for HD textures, but I always found that to be a rather weak selling point if that would be the only thing. Are there other improvements too?

Maybe some examples from different games?

For example, related to the naming problem: we have `Final Fantasy X | X-2 HD Remaster` and `Age of Empires II Remake`.

Comment: I doubt there is any standard. It's mostly marketing.

Comment: I agree with DJ Pirtu. It's very subjective and there is no hard definition, but `remastered` has for me a stronger impact: I would give a game the title `remake` if there wouldn't be any features, just a renewing of graphics etc. while `remastered` should involve new features and just keep the basic idea of the origin.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 for me it's the opposite. In music, remastered means the mix was redone with newer technology, thus improving the quality of the sound. Remake to me seems like it's been recreated like the original game, but with features added and/or changed.

Comment: @Chippies But think about it like this, with a remastered soundtrack, you're not recording the song again, you're taking an old recording and making it better.

Comment: @Chippies According to the answers and I recherched also a bit (e.g. http://dispatches.cheatcc.com/1073) more people see it like you. Nevertheless a highly-subjective topic imho.

Comment: @Chippies I can see your point, but I do not trust whoever names _video games_ to adhere to these very strictly. In an ideal world, this this would be true, but I fear that the reality is a coin toss.

Comment: @Chippies: in music and movies, *remastered* means that a new *master* copy for mass duplication is put together from the original elements (akin to the typesetting of a new edition of a book from the manuscript), which typically involves *some* effort to get things right, including cleaning up the negatives, doing minor fix-ups to the sound, et cetera. Then there is whatever Lucas loves to do, but that's... different. *Remastered* games are often the same, i.e. the original art and sound elements are possibly rescanned at higher res and shipped with an improved engine. See: Grim Fandango.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 If we suppose that words *remake* and *remaster* are transferred from music industry, the meaning is oposite to your explanation.  *Master* is in this context the recording that will be copied. If something is *remastered* the *master* is repaired (suppressed noise, better balanced) or made from scratch with as few changes as possible. When *remade* the whole recording is made from scratch differently. So I understand *remastered* game using new engine, having better graphics and soud quality and *remade* as a new game based on same story telling.

Comment: @Crowley: nitpicking, "master" usually refers to the *end* product of the audio remastering process. The source material is typically referred to as the "finished mix" (which in turn likely originated from a "multitrack master"). The master is not "repaired", it is made anew.

Comment: A remake is when very little code and assets from the original project is used, and a remaster is when the game is touched up (e.g, improved graphics) but uses the same original code and engine.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remaster#Video_games and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_remake

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Although it seems like the terms are often used interchangeably within the industry and marketing, there IS a technical difference between the terms:

> A remake typically shares very little of the original assets and code with the original game, distinguishing it from an "enhanced port", partial remake, or remastering.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_remake

In essence, the difference comes down to just how much of the original game code and assets are used, with a "Remastered" title only updating graphics, whilst a "Remake" could, potentially, include radical changes in gameplay.

> An example of a game that has had its graphics redesigned is Halo: Combat Evolved Anniversary,[11] while the core character and level information is exactly the same as in Halo: Combat Evolved.[11][12][13]

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remaster#Video_games

To use the Bethesda example, Skyrim with updated graphics only would be considered a Remaster, whilst (and good god I personally want this to happen) a version of Morrowind with both updated graphics and a Skyrim-esque combat system would be considered a Remake.

Hope that helps.

UPDATE: Having asked a friend who used to work within the industry (on several remastered titles), he confirms this is the way it is supposed to be used. He also said, however, that even  within development and testing the words were often used interchangeably both verbally and on documents.

Comment: +1 Remake, meaning "to make it again" versus remaster, meaning "to produce a (higher fidelity) primary recording". The very definitions, found in a dictionary, give us an idea of which word we should be using for which case.

Comment: Resident Evil is an example of a game that was remade, then remastered.  The 2002 Gamecube version of Resident Evil was a remake of the Playstation original.  The 2015 HD version was a remastered version of that remake.

Answer (score 4):

"Remaster" would mean they took the original game *(code+assets)* and improved it somehow, usually by improving the graphics and/or adding compatibility with new hardware/OS, but possibly also adding features.

"Remake" means just what it sounds like, they completely remade the game from scratch.

The same applies to things like movies and music also.